# How to implement the OnDemandReportingRendering.ICustomReportItem interface with SSRS 2012

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

**Background**

In our dev. team we are upgrading SSRS 2005 to SSRS 2012 and I am trying to apply the appropriate changes to our code to make it work. Our main problem is that we used Dundas to generate graphs before and since Microsoft bought Dundas and incorporated the component into SSRS by 2008 we need to attend to this in our solution. After some reading on the Internetz I have come to the conclusion that my current task task is to implement a run-time component that I refer to as MReport (another name in production) that implements the ICustomReportItem interface located in the OnDemandReportingRendering namespace.

In our solution with SSRS 2005 we are using Dundas to generate graphs and in the Dundas.ReportingServices namespace there is a class previously used called DundasChart that implements another (older?) version of ICustomReportItem that is completely different from the interface I am trying to comply with. This older ICustomReportItem is located in the ReportRendering  namespace rather than the OnDemandReportRendering namespace. The only reason I believe I should use the latter is because Microsoft let me know that first of all I should use a run-time component to achieve what i want.

The run-time component for a custom report item is called by the report processor at run time. The run-time component accepts data passed by the report processor at run time, processes this data, and returns an image containing the rendered custom report item. (5)

Trying to find exactly how this should be done I haven´t found much but on Technet (1) it clearly states that the ICustomReportItem of interest is located in the OnDemandReportRendering namespace for SQL Server 2012. If one then chooses "Other Versions" and SQL Server 2005, the ICustomReportItem refers to the other interface located simply under ReportRendering.

**Problem**

**Loading the assembly**

The first problem I get is that after deploying I get the following warning upon calling the Render method on the ReportExecutionService (generated proxy class):
*The ‘MReport’ extension failed to load the extension assembly. The custom reportitem ‘CustomMarcusChart’ will render the AltReportItem or preserve the white space if no AltReportItem is explicitly defined.*

EventViewer completes:
*Report Server (SQL2012) cannot load the MReport extension.*

Note that although I get this warning I can still set breakpoints in the MReport class for which the symbols are loaded when I attach my debugger to the ReportingServices process, hinting that the assembly is somehow loaded after all.

I have followed the procedures of deploying a CustomReportItem to the extent I thought it was possible, please correct me if I have made any mistakes:

- Implemented the MReport class in a class library named MarcusReports
  (my code is taken directly from Microsoft (1)(4) )
- Built the class library as a .NET 3.5 assembly
- Copied the DLL and PDB-files to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.SQL2012\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin\ ,
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
  10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies and C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies
- Added a CodeGroup element to rssrvpolicy.config (2)
- Added a ReportItem element to the rsreportserver.config (3) - This is one stage where I am uncertain about how to specify the type
  correctly

**Retrieving the data from the CustomReportItem provided as parameter to the GenerateReportItemDefinition and EvaluateReportItemInstance**

Previously, Dundas simply gave us the generated image but it seems now I have to implement the behaviour myself with the help of this new ICustomReportItem interface, which leads me to the second problem. In the older ICustomerReportItem there was a property, CustomData, that was set (I think) directly by SSRS before invoking a Process method. The CustomData held all necessary data to generate the graph and return it. In the new ICustomerReportItem interface there is no such member, just two method stubs. However, a CustomerReportItem instance is passed to theses methods as parameters and one would believe that the CustomData on the CustomerReportItem would hold the necessary graph data but it does not, or at least not in the structure we are expecting, with series and x/y labels.

Is there anywhere I can read up on how to implement this. I haven´t found any good material or good explanations of how to actually use the new ICustomerReportItem interface to generate a custom graph image.

Sources:

1) http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345254(v=sql.110).aspx

2)

```
           <CodeGroup
              class="UnionCodeGroup"
              version="1"
              PermissionSetName="FullTrust"
              Description="This code group grants MyCustomReportItem.dll FullTrust permission. ">
              <IMembershipCondition class="UrlMembershipCondition" version="1" Url="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.SQL2012\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin\MarcusReports.dll" />
           </CodeGroup>
```

3)

```
 <ReportItems>
    <ReportItem Name="MReport" Type="MarcusReports.MReport,MReport"/>
 </ReportItems>
```

4)

```
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandReportRendering;

namespace MarcusReports
{
    public class MReport : ICustomReportItem
    {
        public void GenerateReportItemDefinition(CustomReportItem cri)
        {
            // Create the Image object that will be
            // used to render the custom report item
            cri.CreateCriImageDefinition();
            var polygonImage = (Image )cri.GeneratedReportItem;
        }

        public void EvaluateReportItemInstance(CustomReportItem cri)
        {
            // Get the Image definition
            var polygonImage = (Image )cri.GeneratedReportItem;

            // Create the image for the custom report item
            polygonImage.ImageInstance.ImageData = DrawImage(cri);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates an image of the CustomReportItem's name
        /// </summary>
        private static byte[] DrawImage( ReportItem customReportItem)
        {
            var width = 1;          // pixels
            var height = 1;         // pixels
            const int resolution = 75; // dpi

            var bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(width, height);
            bitmap.SetResolution(resolution, resolution);

            var graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics .FromImage(bitmap);
            graphics.PageUnit = System.Drawing. GraphicsUnit.Pixel;

            // Get the Font for the Text
            var font = new System.Drawing.Font(System.Drawing.FontFamily .GenericMonospace, 12, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular);

            // Get the Brush for drawing the Text
            var brush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color .LightGreen);

            // Get the measurements for the image
            var maxStringSize = graphics.MeasureString(customReportItem.Name, font);
            width = ( int)(maxStringSize.Width + 2 * font.GetHeight(resolution));
            height = ( int)(maxStringSize.Height + 2 * font.GetHeight(resolution));

            bitmap.Dispose();
            bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap (width, height);
            bitmap.SetResolution(resolution, resolution);

            graphics.Dispose();
            graphics = System.Drawing. Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
            graphics.PageUnit = System.Drawing. GraphicsUnit.Pixel;

            // Draw the text
            graphics.DrawString(customReportItem.Name, font, brush, font.GetHeight(resolution),font.GetHeight(resolution));

            // Create the byte array of the image data
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            bitmap.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            var imageData = new byte[memoryStream.Length];
            memoryStream.Read(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);

            return imageData;
        }
    }
}
```

5) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345219.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Update. I have solved the first problem by updating Type in rsreportserver.config. Apparently I made a mistake when I put MarcusReports.MReport, MReport since MReport is not the AssemblyName which should actually be the second input.

Type is specified as `Namespace.class,Assembly name`

So, after changing the registration of my CustomReportItem in rsreportserver.config to the snippet below I can now deploy and get it to run fine. The problem with CustomData and how to find the values remain. After iterating over the structures in cri.CustomData no values can be found. Any ideas?

```
<ReportItems>
     <ReportItem Name="MReport" Type="MarcusReports.MReport,MarcusReports"/>
</ReportItems>
```